# Gauss-Seidal implementation

Tags: c, mathematics, matrix

The code is an implementation of the [Gauss–Seidel method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method). I would like a general review of the code.

PS: I use code::blocks IDE

```
//generalized code for gauss seidal iteration method 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

#define chk_end 0.01

int row_lim=0,col_lim=0;

float** partial_pivot(float** mat,int row,int col);//finds the pivot of matrix
int condition(float* result,float* temp,int row);//checks the terminating condition
float* final_result(float** mat,float* result,int row,int col);//calculates final result
float** create_mat(float** mat,int row,int col);//creates a matrix of row X col
float** feed_mat(float** mat,int row,int col);//inputs value in matrix
void disp_mat(float** mat,int row,int col);//displays matrix

float** partial_pivot(float** mat,int row,int col)
{
 float pivot;
 int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0;

 if(row_lim<row)
 {
  for(i=0,j=col_lim;i<row-1;i++)
  {
   for(l=row_lim;l<row-i-1;l++)
   {
   if(mat[l][j]<mat[l+1][j])
   {
    for(k=0;k<col;k++)
    {
     pivot=mat[l+1][k];
     mat[l+1][k]=mat[l][k];
     mat[l][k]=pivot;
    }
   }
   }
  }
 row_lim++;
 col_lim++;
 partial_pivot(mat,row,col);
 }

 return mat;
}

int condition(float* result,float* temp,int row)
{
 int i=0,flag = 0;

 for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 {
 if(result[i] > temp[i])
 {
  if((result[i]-temp[i]) < chk_end)
  {
   flag = 1;
  }
  else
  {
   flag = 0;
   break;
  }
 }

 else
 {
  if((temp[i]-result[i]) < chk_end)
  {
   flag = 1;
  }
  else
  {
   flag = 0;
   break;
  }
 }
 }

 return flag;
}

float* final_result(float** mat,float* result,int row,int col)
{
 int k=0,i=0,j=0;
 float T = 0;
 float *temp;

 temp=(float*)malloc((row)*sizeof(float));//Edit: row-1 changed to row
 for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 {
  temp[i] = 0;
 }

 printf("Processing result ... \n");


 do
 { 
   for(k=0;k<row;k++)
   temp[i] = result[i];    //was a logical error, sorry
   {
   for(i=0;i<row;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<(col-1);j++)
    {
     if(i==j)
     {

     }
     else
     {
      T += (mat[i][j])*(temp[j]);
     }
    }
    result[i] = ((mat[i][col-1] - T)/(mat[i][i]));
    //temp[i] = result[i];
    T=0;
   }
  }
 }
 while(condition(result,temp,row) == 0);

 free(temp);

 return result;
}

float** create_mat(float** mat,int row,int col)
{
    int i=0;

     mat=(float**)malloc((row)*sizeof(float*));//Edit: row-1 changed to row
     if(mat)
     {
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            mat[i]=(float*)malloc((col)*sizeof(float));//Edit: col-1 changed to col
        }
     }

    return mat;
}

float** feed_mat(float** mat,int row,int col)
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter mat[%d][%d] element:\n",i,j);
            scanf("%f",&mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return mat;
}

void disp_mat(float** mat,int row,int col)
{
    int i=0,j=0;

     for(i=0;i<row;i++)
     {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("\t%f",mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }

}

int main()
{
 float **mat,*result;
 int i=0,row=0,col=0;

 mat=NULL;

 printf("Enter the number of Equations :\n");
 scanf("%d",&row);
 col=row+1;

 result = (float*)malloc((row)*sizeof(float));//Edit: row-1 changed to row
 for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 {
  result[i] = 0;
 }

 mat=create_mat(mat,row,col);

 printf("Enter the values in the %d x %d matrix:\n",row,col);
 mat=feed_mat(mat,row,col);

 printf("matrix entered by you:\n");
 disp_mat(mat,row,col);

 mat=partial_pivot(mat,row,col);

 printf("pivoted matrix entered:\n");
 disp_mat(mat,row,col);

 result = final_result(mat,result,row,col);

 printf("\nResult is : \n");
 for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 {
  printf("  x[%d]   %f",i,result[i]);
 }

 for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 {
     free(mat[i]);
 }
 free(mat);

 free(result);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A word of warning: I am very much a C newbie myself, so it may be good to take my advice with a grain of salt.

### Formatting

The only good thing I can say about your formatting is that it's consistent. But a 1-space indent really isn't readable. I recommend 4 spaces instead. Please put some whitespace around your operators: a space after every comma, a space on each side of `=`, `-`, `+`, `*`, …. Don't cram multiple assignments on one line: I find

```
int i, j, k;
```

or

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
```

acceptable, but not `int i=0,j=0,k=0;`.

If you are targetting a C89-compatible environment, this is as far as we can go. I recommend you move on (e.g. to C++ or C99), where we can put the declaration of `for`-loop variables inside the loop itself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < whatever; i++)
```

… and we also don't have to put all declarations at the top of each scope – just declare your variables at the point of first use.

### `malloc` and error handling

Always check the return value of malloc:

```
float *temp = (float*) malloc(row * sizeof(float));
if (temp == NULL)
{
    /* return some error code */
}
```

### C isn't object oriented, but whatever

You always bundle the three variables `mat`, `row`, `col`. I suggest you put those into a struct, and pass this single struct around instead:

```
typedef struct {
    float **mat;
    int rows;
    int cols;
} Matrix;
```

I would then create a `Matrix_new` function that creates and populates an instance, e.g.

```
// this code assumes C99. Ignore my more compact brace style.

/**
 * Allocates a new `Matrix` instance. Returns a pointer to the instance on
 * success, a `NULL` pointer on failure.
 *
 * A Matrix must always be freed via `Matrix_destroy(instance)`!
 */

Matrix*
Matrix_new(int rows, int cols) {

    Matrix* matrix = (Matrix*) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if (matrix == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    float** mat = (float**) malloc(rows * sizeof(float*));
    if (mat == NULL) {
        free(matrix);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        float* row = (float*) malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
        if (row == NULL) {
            // if a row allocation fails, we have to `free` the previous rows.
            i--;
            for (; i >= 0; i--) {
                free(mat[i]);
            }
            free(mat);
            free(matrix);
            return NULL;
        }

    }

    matrix->mat  = mat;
    matrix->rows = rows;
    matrix->cols = cols;
    return matrix;
}
```

and of course, a mirroring `Matrix_destroy`:

```
/**
 * Safely frees a Matrix instance.
 */

int
Matrix_destroy(Matrix* matrix) {

    if (matrix == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    float** mat = matrix->mat;
    int rows = matrix->rows;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(mat[i]);
    }

    free(mat);
    free(matrix);

    return 1;
}
```

Then, you can rewrite your other methods to take advantage of this bundling.

### Return values

Very often (e.g. in `final_result`, `create_mat`, `feed_mat`), you return a pointer from your function even when that pointer was an argument to that function. It is generally preferable to return an error code, and to return values via pointers/out-arguments.

For example, `final_result` could be changed to:

```
/**
 * Calculates the final result.
 *
 * Returns an error code.
 *
 * After successful execution, the `out_result` pointer will point to the 
 * result, which is a `float*` of `self->rows` length. The caller owns the
 * result, and is responsible for calling `free(*out_result)`.
 *
 * Example usage:
 *
 *     float *result;
 *     if (! final_result(matrix, &result)) {
 *         // abort with error
 *     }
 *     // do something with `result`:
 *     for (int i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) {
 *         printf("%f\n", result[i]);
 *     }
 *     free(result);
 */

int
final_result(Matrix* self, float** out_result) {
    if (self == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    float* temp = (float*) malloc(self->rows * sizeof(float));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    float* result = (float*) malloc(self->rows * sizeof(float));
    if (result == NULL) {
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < self->rows; i++) {
        temp[i]   = 0;
        result[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("Processing result...\n");

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < self->rows; i++) {
            float T = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < self->cols - 1; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    T += self->mat[i][j] * temp[j];
                }
            }
            result[i] = (self->mat[i][self->cols - 1] - T) / self->mat[i][i];
            temp[i] = result[i];
        }
    } while (condition(result, temp, self->rows) == 0);

    free(temp);
    *out_result = result;
    return 1;
}
```

### Miscellaneous Helper Functions

#### `memset`

When zeroing all elements in some data structure, you can often use `memset` from `string.h` instead:

```
temp=(float*)malloc((row)*sizeof(float));//Edit: row-1 changed to row
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
 temp[i] = 0;
}
```

becomes

```
float* temp = (float*) malloc(row * sizeof(float));
if (temp == NULL) {
    // return error code
}
memset(temp, 0, row * sizeof(float));
```

#### `fabsf`

If you are interested in an absolute value of a float, use the `fabsf` function from `math.h`. With it, your `condition` function simplifies to:

```
int
condition(float* result, float* temp, int row) {
    int flag = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        if (fabsf(temp[i] - result[i]) < chk_end) {
            flag = 1;
        }
        else {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: dude heartly thanks a highly detailed way of making my program optimized and thanks for spending time on it,, i am having one doubt on your point please just elaborate what you want to say through it i.e.                         /*Return values

Very often (e.g. in final_result, create_mat, feed_mat), you return a pointer from your function even when that pointer was an argument to that function. It is generally preferable to return an error code, and to return values via pointers/out-arguments. */                                //what do you mean by return values via pointers/out-arguments//

Comment: @Amitesh I added an example rewrite of `final_result` that showcases this: The return value is a status code, whereas the result is returned via a pointer argument. In this simple case, this isn't really necessary, but quite often you'll want to return multiple values from a function: pointer arguments are the best way to do that.

Comment: thanks dude got your point and will optimize my code by using your tips thanks.